# Obtaining Wold Representation of VECM Model

Tags: econometrics, time-series

I'm attempting to replicate [Beaudry & Portier (2006)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1257/pol.1.1.25810.1257/aer.96.4.1293), and I'm having trouble coding up the long-run restrictions in the VECM model. Specifically I'm having a hard time finding a clear explanation of dealing with the error-correction term when getting MA($\infty$) representation. Any references would help! Most papers just assumes you know how to do it.

Comment: You want to write your own code? They make available their MATLAB code and the [ReplicationWiki shows there already was a replication](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Stock_Prices,_News,_and_Economic_Fluctuations_%28AER_2006%29). You can use the discussion pages to bring up any questions you have about it.

Comment: It was for a school project. Fortunately the paper on replicationWiki was a bit more informative than the original paper.